# Expanding Alias in csh or tcsh

Tags: unix, alias, solaris, csh, tcsh

I have a following lengthy command to execute.

```
ftest ftype itype ntype:node_number
```

**ftest ftype itype ntype:** --> is the command.

**node_number**  --> is the parameter (will be an integer in the range 0-10000).

I've aliased the command to **fntype** as below.

```
alias fntype 'ftest ftype itype ntype:'
```

When I execute the command alias with a node number, I'm getting the **command not found** error.

```
[tspot@mypi : ~/src/bin]$ fntype1000
fntype1000: Command not found.
```

I see the alias is not expanding and **fntype1000** is considered a single command resulting in **command not found** error.

When I run the command by using the lengthy command with parameter, it just works fine.

```
[tspot@mypi : ~/src/bin]$ ftest ftype itype ntype:1000
1000 is mapped to i/o device memory pointing to 0xff0ac005.
```

I need to know if there is a way to expand an alias in a shell commandline.

Note: I'm running Solaris on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try

```
alias fntype 'ftest ftype itype ntype:\!^'
```

In this case you can call `fntype 1000` (note the space between the command and parameter). More details read the manual page, "History substitution" section.